# No package matching 'docker-ce' is available with ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

On ubuntu 18.04 I am running this ansible (version 2.5.1) role:

```
---
- name: Add Docker apt repository key.
  apt_key:
    url: "https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg"
    state: present

- name: gather facts
  setup:    

- name: Set the stable docker repository
  apt_repository: 
    repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} stable"
    state: present
    update_cache: yes    

- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    name: docker-ce
    state: present
```

With this playbook:

```
---


- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  become: true

  pre_tasks:
  - name: Install python for Ansible
    raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)

  tasks:  
  - name: Install list of packages
    apt: name={{item}} state=latest
    with_items:
         - nano
         - git
         - htop
         - gitg

  roles:
      - {role: 'docker', tags: 'docker'}
```

But I get the following error:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install python for Ansible] **************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [docker : Add Docker apt repository key.] *************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [docker : gather facts] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [docker : Set the stable docker repository] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [docker : Install Docker] *****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'docker-ce' is available"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/repos/ansible-vps/src/ansible_create_workstation.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

So for some reason the docker-ce package cannot be found, has that changed recently or is it something else I am doing wrong?

Also when I look in: **/etc/apt/sources.list** it does not contain a:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  ...
```

entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use **edge** instead of **stable** with bionic (18.04), it will be in stable in the future.

```
- name: Set the stable docker repository
  apt_repository: 
    repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} edge"
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the cause was trying to install `docker-ce` on an `arm64` Raspberry Pi OS version, when docker upstream doesn't seem to offer `docker-ce:arm64`, only a variant for a different architecture: `docker-ce:armhf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a matching post on StackOverflow :
[Ansible: no package available for docker-ce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050128/ansible-no-package-available-for-docker-ce).

The accepted answer says :

> Or you can use generic OS package manager module if Ansible version >=
>   2.0:
>
> ```
> - name: install docker
>   package:
>     name: docker-ce
>     state: present
> ```

A comment below says :

> replace `$(lsb_release -cs)` with `xenial` (for ubuntu 16.04) from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and retry

Answer (score 0):

One could also check ansible-galaxy first and use a well tested ansible role like https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-docker. No need to reinvent the wheel.